# TreeView list of folders recursively with icons from cache and NO duplicates in ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, icons, pinvoke

I will be providing a non-recursive demonstration of this as it is sufficient to outline and reproduce the problem I am having.

I would like to get the folder icon as is used in a parallel thread friendly manner, but I would also like to ensure that only ONE of each image found is stored in the ImageList so, if there are 100 folders, and 97 of them use the system folder icon, 2 uses a recycle bin icon, and 1 uses a Drive icon, I only want 3 icons in the ImageList.

The following code sets the 'root' folder of the treeview control it is a part of:

```
public void SetRoot(string path)
{
    Tag = path;
    var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).OrderBy(d => d).Select(d => d.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last());
    TreeNode node;
    string folder;
    foreach (var d in dirs) {
        node = Nodes.Add(d);
        folder = Path.Combine(path, d);

        // some check to see if the image is in the list already, if not add it, else get the index of the image in the list and don't add again            
        // set to int ImageListIconIndex

        // ImageList.Add( ..... code here for icon ..... );
        Nodes.Add(d,d, ImageListIconIndex);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following api calls :

**P/Invoke**

> ExtractIcon / ExtractIconEx

*These calls only seem to work on files*

---

**Native call**

> Icon.GetAssociatedIcon

*This also only seems to work on files*

---

I did some digging and found a couple API's which at a glance look like they might work, but are very poorly documented (even p/invoke 's site has very little to say aside from the declaration) which are as follows :

[LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074(v=vs.85).aspx) - *There is very little information about how to use this API. I was able to assign a declaration from the information [here on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx.html) and here is it's sister call [LookupIconIdFromDirectory](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/LookupIconIdFromDirectory.html)

These calls appear to require another call to actually load the resource, but given the lack of documentation on this API, it is pretty much a guessing game to determine what those calls are ( `GetResourceEx` perhaps ), or which files/part of the system they would call to translate that icon Id (Lookup Icon Id From Directory) into an actual Icon image.

The end goal, is to be able to (as efficiently and quickly as possible - without loading the actual image or image pointer into memory until after it has been confirmed that it needs to be added to the in memory `ImageList`) only load and add new icons to the treeview image list if the icon does not exist in the list.  I like the theoretical concept of getting the id of an image (what `LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx` implies it does), and checking if I have that id in my list, and if not, get the icon by that id, and  add it to my treeview imagelist.

Comment: Try using [`SHGetFileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx) function, it retrieves information about an object in the file system (including folders). Then check the value of `iIcon` member from the retrieved [`SHFILEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759792.aspx) structure. The `SHFILEINFO.iIcon` is the index of the icon within the system image list, I'm guessing you could probably use it as item key in your ImageList.

Comment: @IronGeek - I had trouble when using SHGetFileInfo to retrieve icon information when using parallel threading (aka, async/await `*.WaitAll( tasks );`   where `tasks` is the list of tasks that internally await the return of the SHGetFileInfo stuff,  (wrapped in Task.Run().  The problem it exhibited is it would randomly skip icons returning null when the system does have an icon.  Use of Icon.GetAssociatedIcon( file )    inside the task resolved the problem.